# 3G dongle and wire connection at the same time

Tags: internet

Heyhey

I have a dongle and an adsl connection. Since the dongle has lower ping I prefer to use that, however sometimes it gets disconnected. Do you know how can I set up (if possible) to use windows the dongle 3G connection first and if that gets disconnected, then the wifi?

Thanks